# How to prevent windows from minimizing when switching to other applications?

Tags: window-manager

I switch between multiple workspaces that are dedicated to various activities (e.g. a music listening workspace using Spotify, a chat workspace using Slack, email on another workspace, etc).

One issue that's cropped up recently is that when I switch to a different workspace and application, *other applications* are minimized on all workspaces after >30 seconds. This means when I switch from music to chat workspace, the other application is minimized and I need to re-open it from the dock.

This does not affect windows of the same application (e.g. Chrome windows open on different workspaces). It's a bit frustrating that I have to maximize windows every time I switch between workspaces and I can't figure how this behavior has changed in the past week or two.

I don't know if this is related or not, but a few weeks ago I was trying to find a way to rebind the hide all applications keyboard shortcut since I was trying to use that same shortcut in another app ([Rectangle](https://rectangleapp.com/)). In trying to do that, I ran this command in the terminal: `defaults write "Apple Global Domain" NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "Hide Others" nil`

Comment: I switch between 5 or 6 programs running simultaneously and don't have any windows minimising - they all stay where I leave them. I won't try that bit of code you show though...

Answer (score 0):

I should've dug into that `defaults` command sooner. I fixed it by reading the manpage for `defaults`, confirming that there was only a single setting set, removing it, and restarting my laptop.

1. `man defaults`
2. `defaults read "Apple Global Domain" NSUserKeyEquivalents`
3. `defaults delete "Apple Global Domain" NSUserKeyEquivalents`
4. restart laptop